# Rails: Dynamically created forms - how to accept answers for questions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, dynamic, ruby-on-rails-4, nested

I have looked on the internet and stared at my screen for hours now and hope that you guys can help me out and can stop me from thinking in circles :) I've already found http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 and http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2 but still can't get my mind around it...

**Context**

I'm trying to develop a CMS where users can create dynamic forms, with their own specific questions, question help text and possible answers (in case of radio buttons/checkboxes)

I am able to create the questions and the forms and to show the question in the viewer, my next step is to allow other users to answer the questions, but can't figure out how to do that.

What I have so far:

Form model:

```
has_many :custom_questions
has_many :custom_themes
has_many :form_submissions
has_many :answers
accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
```

Question model

```
 belongs_to :custom_form
belongs_to :custom_theme

has_many :possible_answers
accepts_nested_attributes_for :possible_answers

has_many :answers
accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
```

Answer model

```
belongs_to :custom_questions
belongs_to :possible_answers
belongs_to :form_submissions
```

and the viewer which I use to load the questions and input fields:

```
<div class='content custom_forms clearfix'>

    <%= form_for @customForm do |f| %>
        <ul>
            <%= @customForm.custom_themes.order(:order).each do |theme| %>


                <div class='align_element'>
                    <section class='form_theme_title clearfix'><%=  raw theme.theme_title %></section>
                    <section class="form_theme_description clearfix"><%= raw theme.theme_description.linkify %></section>
                </div>
                <ul class='selfce-reviews-table clearfix'>
                    <%= render "reviews/tabHeader" %>
                    <li class='row clearfix'>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="clearfix">
                                <% theme.custom_questions.order(:order).each do |question| %>

                                    <li class='column selfc'>

                                    </li>

                                    <li class='column rev'>
                                        <div class='align_element'>

                                        <section class='form_question clearfix'>
                                            <%= raw question.question %>
                                        </section>
                                        <section class="form_description clearfix">
                                            <%= raw question.description.linkify %> 
                                        </section>

                                        <%= f.fields_for question.answers.build do |builder| %>
                                            <%= builder.hidden_field :custom_question_id, value: question.id %>
                                            <% if question.q_type == "textfield"    or question.q_type.nil? %>
                                                <%= builder.text_field :answer, class:'reviews-inputBox clearfix' %>
                                            <% elsif question.q_type == "textarea" %>
                                                <%= builder.text_area :answer, class:'reviews-inputTextarea clearfix tinymce' %>

                                                <%= tinymce %>
                                            <% elsif question.q_type == "checkbox" %>

                                            <%  elsif question.q_type == "radio-button" %>

                                            <% end      %>
                                        <% end %>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                <% end %>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <%= f.submit %>
                    </li>
            <% end %>

        </ul>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

What I want is to store each answer in the table "answers" in the fields:
- question_id which refers to the unique id of the question
- answer - the value of the input field

As you can see I use @customForm which is the generated form by the administrator. I assume I use it here in the wrong way, because I don't want to update the form but only the answers... so instead it should be something like form_for :answers but that doesnt seem to work..

**So my first question:**
The way I see it every answer is unique and should therefore be seen as a unique form, hence my nested forms.. However if I use my code right now every input field has the same id: "custom_form_answer_answer". Is there a way I don't have to use nested forms to load the input fields for each question, e.g. by giving each answer a unique id based on the question_id?

I can't hardcode the inputfield name since this can change any time the user creates a new field..

**My second question**
If there is a way to do that.. how can I save the answers then..

Please let me know if you need any addition information.. and please keep in mind I'm fairly new to rails... so still learning!

Thanks! =-)

Comment: figured it out myself...

I created a second class "submissions" which had the form and accepted attributes for answers... it was that easy.. think I just had been staring at my screen too long